# Populating a ListView with an AlertDialog in android

Tags: android

I am very new to android.
I have searched for two days, but don't understand how to make my project work...
I am doing an android based project which is a virtual wallet where every user should save their personal information.
I have a Button. When I click it, an AlertDialog pops, consisting of two EditTexts for name and email.
When I click on the SAVE button inside the AlertDialog, the name and email is saved into the ListView as one row.
Then clicking on the Add Button, another record will be saved.
Please, help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little bit confused with your question. I don't know what you expect to get with it, so answering to the question's title, here is how you populate a ListView in an AlertDialog:

Create a view containing the dialog's content:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_content, null);
```

Declare the views you need from that layout (note that you need to call *findViewById()* in the dialog's view, in this case, it's called *layout*):

```
ListView listview = (ListView) layout.findViewById(R.id.dialog_content_listview);
```

Add the view to the AlertDialog.Builder:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
builder.setView(layout);
// other assigns;
AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
```

Now it is like any other layout, it doesn't matter if it is in a Dialog. You can handle this like in a normal Activity (instantiate an Adapter, and then call `listview.setAdapter(adapter)` to set it).